# Have a 500 error on live hosting using Laravel App

Tags: laravel, hosting, http-status-code-500

Can you help me to fix this issue?

I uploaded all files to hosting with all requirements needed (PHP 7.4) and now I see 500 error page. All scripts are working in the public_html directory, but Laravel doesn't.

The configuration is here: http://fratelli.md/info.php

Comment: seems that you are using PHP 7.4 please have a check your web.config file and check you php version there as well

Comment: I haven't a web.config file on the server :-(

Comment: i need to check remotely for your concern